# Shiny: dynamic default value for textInput

Tags: r, shiny

I see that `textInput` has a default value field. However, I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically set the default value field. Lets say I have a `selectInput`, I want the default value of my `textInput` to be the value selected in `selectInput` but with some text appended to it, which the user can freely edit.

On the `ui` side where I have the `textInput` I obviously can't do anything like `value=paste0(output$selectName,"_someText")` because I can't use `output`.

I'm guessing the answer involves some code on the `server` side that updates the `textInput`. I can't seem to figure how to get `updateTextInput` to do what I want, even though it sounds like what I want. Any advice on dynamically generating a default value for a `textInput` would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I needed to use `observe` in the `server` side and then `updateTextInput` worked.

Comment: cool that you figured it out, but would've been much more beneficial to others if you posted a working example at the very least